# Python Regex - replacing consecutive punctuation

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of online reviews, and I would like to replace things such as "
`,,,` or `!!` with `,` and `!`, respectively, for example.
I think my question boils down twofold:

1. How do I compile a regex pattern to detect two+ back-to-back punctuation?
2. Upon some method such as replace, how do I retrieve which particular pattern was detected? So that I could use that pattern to replace its consecutiveness.

As an extension, how about replacing weird punctuation that you may see in Tweets such as `!! ! :)` ?

Any guidance helps.

Comment: What have you tried? You can use https://regex101.com/ to play around with regular expressions (set Python flavor). Regarding 2. the `sub` method allows a  function as `repl` parameter to choose replacement dependent on found pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `re.sub` here:

```py
inp = "Hello World!!!"
output = re.sub(r'([!?,;])\1+', r'\1', inp)
print(inp + "\n" + output)
```

This prints:

```
Hello World!!!
Hello World!
```

You may expand the character class `[!?,;]` to include other punctuation characters as you want.